configure.ac proper syntax
ALL,
Im adding the following in my configure,ac:
AX_HAVE_QT()
if have_qt=yes ; then
    MY_CXXFLAGS+=@(QT_CXXFLAGS)@
    MY_LIBS+=@(QT_LIBS)@
fi
AC_SUBST(MY_CXXFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(MY_LBS)

problem is, after running autoreconf and configure the latter fails with:
../configure: line 6546: syntax error near unexpected token `('
../configure: line 6546: `        MY_CXXFLAGS+=@(QT_CXXFLAGS)@'
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

What would be the proper syntax to reference the variable in configure?
TIA!!

I’m pretty sure the syntax for variable substitutions is @X@, not @(X)@.

@nneonneo, and then I guess the same should happen in the Makefile.am, right? Use @MY_CXXFLAGS@?

Regarding the edit: this is a separate question.  However, I would be inclined to guess that AX_HAVE_QT is not finding your Qt installation.  That macro emits "checking..." messages that you should see in configure's output, by which you should be able to confirm (or deny).  As we've discussed before, that macro is looking in the executable search path for qmake, including also under the names qmake-qt5 and qmake-qt6.

@JohnBollinger, no that was my mistake. That's why I later deleted the edit. I used -q with the grep(quiet) option, which doesn't produce anything.

Macros in configure.ac are expanded via m4 to produce a POSIX shell script (configure).  Thus, anything in configure.ac that is not a macro invocation must be in shell syntax.  Additionally, output variables determined by configure are shell variables to configure itself.  The @...@ syntax for interpolating them applies only to templates that are processed by configure (actually by generated script config.status).  Most common among those is Makefile.in, but there can be others.
So,
AX_HAVE_QT()
if [ "$have_qt" = yes ]; then
    MY_CXXFLAGS="$MY_CXXFLAGS $QT_CXXFLAGS"
    MY_LIBS="$MY_LIBS $QT_LIBS"
fi
AC_SUBST([MY_CXXFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([MY_LBS])

or
AX_HAVE_QT()
if test "$have_qt" = yes; then
    MY_CXXFLAGS="$MY_CXXFLAGS $QT_CXXFLAGS"
    MY_LIBS="$MY_LIBS $QT_LIBS"
fi
AC_SUBST([MY_CXXFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([MY_LBS])

However, the manual asserts that

If an if command is not inside AC_DEFUN, and it contains calls to Autoconf macros, it should be rewritten using AS_IF.

Your particular example does not meet those criteria, but you could use AS_IF anyway:
AX_HAVE_QT()
AS_IF([test "$have_qt" = yes], [
  MY_CXXFLAGS="$MY_CXXFLAGS $QT_CXXFLAGS"
  MY_LIBS="$MY_LIBS $QT_LIBS"
])
AC_SUBST([MY_CXXFLAGS])
AC_SUBST([MY_LBS])

Also, the manual used to recommend that conditionals such as yours be expressed in a way that avoids either operand expanding to an empty string (even a quoted one).  That is, test "x$have_qt" = xyes.  You can still do that, and you will find many examples of it, but these days, your configure scripts are unlikely ever to run on a shell where it makes a difference.

OK so now +=, then. Pity. ;-) Now, what is the difference between those 2 syntax - using AS_IF() vs. not using it? According to the docs I have to use AS_IF()

@Igor, the difference between the two (three, actually) conditional syntaxes is nil for your particular case.  The macro-based one will expand to something very like the middle, test-based one.  You should be able to find it in the generated configure script to see.  However, as the manual describes (already quoted), you should use the macro-based one if the test or body of the conditional contains any Autoconf macros.  And as this answer already states, you can use it under other circumstances, too.

thx for the explanation. It worked.
